# How to convert Java Map containing List to Scala map

Tags: java, scala, dictionary, types

Scala 2.11
There is a `jmap` variable of type:

```
val jmap: java.util.Map[String, java.util.List[Double]]
```

The `jmap` is converted to Scala map:

```
val smap: Map[String, java.util.List[Double]] = jmap.asScala.toMap
```

The purpose is to cast it to `Map[String, List[Double]]` in Scala
I found this procedure:

```
smap.mapValues(_.asScala.toList)
```

But unfortunately it generates `MapLike` instead of desired type `Map[String, List[Double]]`

Comment: Are you using scala 2.12 or 2.13?

Comment: you should be able to get a `Map` instead of a `MapLike` by using an additional `.toMap`

Comment: Note: conversion to a Scala `List` is very much non-trivial; it's not an abstract data type corresponding to `java.util.List`. Unless you need it specifically, I'd prefer `toSeq`.

Comment: can't reproduce problem with scala 2.12. It is ok. Scala 2.13 says that result type is `MapView`, not `MapLike`, but is solved as say @XavierGuihot

Answer (score 2):

In Scala 2.13 try

```
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._

val smap: Map[String, List[Double]] = jmap.asScala.view.mapValues(_.asScala.toList).toMap
```

In Scala 2.11 try

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

val smap: Map[String, List[Double]] = jmap.asScala.mapValues(_.asScala.toList).toMap
```

Comment: How can I do it in Scala 2.11

Comment: Similar alternative: `mapAsScalaMap(jmap).mapValues(_.asScala.toList)`